# Changing time zone on Tomcat 7 application - Openshift

Tags: java, tomcat7, openshift

I have deployed a web application on openshift (free version) and have been struggling to fix the time-zone with no luck. My time zone "Asia/Colombo". How can i do this?

My application is hosted in Apache Tomcat 7 server.

```
   // gives me current date from server time zone
   java.util.Date date = new Date();

   // However for now I manage to fix the issue with below code
   // without having to change it from server side.
   public static Date getNormalizedDate() {

     Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"));
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

     cal.set(Calendar.DATE, today.get(Calendar.DATE));
     cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, today.get(Calendar.MONTH));
     cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, today.get(Calendar.MONTH));
     cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
     cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, today.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
     cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, today.get(Calendar.SECOND));

     return (cal.getTime());
  }
```

Comment: Show the code where the timezone is wrong

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What result are you getting and what did you expect?